# MATLAB Freezes During Save

Tags: matlab

After I create a new script and save the file to my Desktop, when I begin to type into the editor, the entire program hangs and I have to force quit. This happens even when there is text in the editor. I am running MATLAB R2014b on Windows 10. Any known solutions to this dilemma?

Comment: You should definitely at least provide the platform (OS) and matlab version. Still sounds quite obscure... How long did you wait for it to return? What if you don't save it to Desktop but rather somewhere else? What if you don't type into the editor, but into the command window? Have you tried pressing ctrl+c a few times?

Comment: Perchance, are you using Matlab 2015a for Windows? That version had some serious problems with file IO for me. Upgrading to 2015b fixed it.

Comment: Hey @AndrasDeak. Refer to my edits. To answer your questions, it hangs indefinitely, I have to close the program from the Task Manager. If I save the script somewhere else, it'll still freeze. This problem also occurs when I type in the command window. And ctrl+c unfortunately does not work.

Comment: @drhagen Refer to my eidts. I am running R2014b.

Comment: Hmm, Windows 10 and Matlab 2014b came out about the same time (2014 Sep-Oct). I wonder if there is some incompatibility they didn't know about at the time. I would try upgrading to 2015b if you can.

Comment: @drhagen possible: [mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/223444#answer_182374) says "MATLAB R2015a is supported on Windows 10. Earlier releases of MATLAB are not supported and are not guaranteed to work on Windows 10." I guess this means all bets are off.

Comment: Well dang. I can't upgrade  to 2015b as I'm using a student license. Well this sucks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the comments for future users:

[Windows 10 and Matlab 2014b are not compatible](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/223444-is-matlab-compatible-with-windows-10#answer_182374)*. A Windows 10 user must use version 2015a or later.